# How to setup local development environment for Nomad+Consul Service Mesh

Tags: consul, nomad, servicemesh

As per Hashicorp documentation on Nomad+Consul, consul service mesh cannot be run on MacOS/Windows, since it does not support bridge network.

https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/integrations/consul-connect

What is the recommended way to setup a local development environment for Nomad+Consul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to have a look at setting up your local environment using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) (which is also a product for Hashicorp) and [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). There are plenty examples online, for example

- [Here is one](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad-autoscaler-demos/blob/main/vagrant/dynamic-app-sizing/Vagrantfile) of the most recent setup with Nomad and Consul, although it is not parametrised much.
- [Here is one](https://github.com/hashicorp/guides-configuration/blob/master/hashistack/Vagrantfile) with the core Hashicorp stack, i.e. Nomad, Vault and Consul. This repo is quite old but it merely means that it uses old versions of binaries, which should be easy to update.
- [Here is one](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-guides/blob/master/operations/provision-vault/dev/vagrant-local/Vagrantfile) with only Vault and Consul, but you can add Nomad in a similar way. In fact, this Vargrant setup and how files are structured seems to me pretty close to the one above

I've run the first two previous week with a simple

```
vagrant up
```

and it worked almost like a charm. I think, I needed to upgrade my VirtualBox and maybe run `vagrant up` multiple times because of some weird run time errors which I didn't want to debug)

Once Vagrant finishes build you can

```
vagrant ssh
```

to get inside created VM, although configs are setup with mounting volumes/syncing files and all UI components are also exposed at the default ports.